# web.xml in Spring Boot throws Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've generated Spring Boot application with annotation driven configuration.

However I wanted to configure some of the Spring Security with xml configuration because I have already a XML file that does it.

So I've created web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">



</web-app>
```

and added `@ImportResource("classpath:web.xml")` to my `@SpringBootApplication` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:web.xml")
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(new Class[] { Application.class, WebAppInitializer.class }, args);
    }
}
```

And then I get:

> 2016-10-23 13:01:52.888 ERROR 9120 --- [           main]
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for
>   XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee] Offending
>   resource: class path resource [web.xml]

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `web.xml` is no spring beans configuration file, so you must not include it in the spring bean configuration (you must not use `@ImportResource("classpath:web.xml")` )!

- The `web.xml` is to configure your servlet container (for example tomcat).
- The spring beans xml files are to configure Spring

So both are different.

Springs [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html) annotation is for importing spring bean configurations but not for servelt container configurations!

Comment: Ok, obviously I have some gaps as I'm used to annotation solutions. So how can I, for instance, configure filters in web.xml and make it work with Spring Boot?

Comment: Correct, The web.xml is to configure your servlet container (for example tomcat). Instead you can do this for example:   @ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how you can use existing XML (not web.xml)configuration files in your main Spring Boot application(or maybe you have already some Java config that you need to use):

```
@ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml")
@Configuration
public class SimpleConfiguration {
@Autowired
Connection connection; //This comes from the applicationContext.xml file.
@Bean
Database getDatabaseConnection(){
return connection.getDBConnection();
}
// Mode code here....
}
```